# How do I update a parent branch without deleting the clild one in git?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

I know this was answered somewhere but I cannot find the right wording. The question is: If I have a master branch and a master/branch1 branch, and I have commits in it like this:

```
c c
| |
c c
| |
|/  c = commit
```

How can I do something like tihis?

```
c c
| |
c c
|\|
c c
| |
c c
| |
|/
```

And when I do merge gitKraken shows this:

```
c
|\
c c
| |
c c
| |
c/
```

So can I checkout the clild branch after I have merged it?
Side question: If merge does not delete the child branch, how do I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Merging](https://support.gitkraken.com/working-with-repositories/branching-and-merging/#merging) won't delete the child branch.
gitKraken simply focus on your current branch `master` and shows all the reachable commits from the mast (merge) commit on `master`.

If you switch back to the child branch, you would find again the more recent commits (done after the merge), and you can go on working on that branch.

Comment: Thanks but, how do I delete the branch then after I do merge?

Comment: @Leo Merge or not, you can delete a branch at any time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44714712/6309